# Enable to open close port 9090

Tags: port, server, firewall, openfire, ubuntu-server

I am new to ubuntu server. I have tried to open port 9090 on server for openfire but wont able to do so. I have installed ufw on our server.

what I did till now.

**nmap localhost -p 9090**

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-21 12:36 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000044s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
9090/tcp closed zeus-admin
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

output of **sudo ufw status**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9091/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5222/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
7777/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
7443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
7070/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3478/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3479/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
9090/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
9090                       ALLOW       Anywhere
9091/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5222/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7777/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7070/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3478/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3479/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9090 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

delete 9090 port using ufw and add again . But still its showing port closed.

nmap outpu

```
nmap localhost 

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-21 12:42 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00037s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

can anyone please help me what was issue

Comment: Is there really something listening on port 9090? netstat shows it?

Comment: nnetstat -tulpn give me following result. I am trying to install openfire on 9090
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: No netstat -atn doesn't list port 9090 as listening? Then there's nothing wrong with your results: port is closed if no process is listening.

Answer (score 1):

You not only need to allow access to the port with `ufw`, you also need a program to be listening on that port, for it to be considered open.

You can check that there is something listening on port 9090 with commands like `lsof -i :9090` or `netstat -tln | grep 9090`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have applications listening on the port. There are six port states for the nmap results. The `closed` state is `A closed port is accessible (it receives and responds to Nmap probe packets), but there is no application listening on it.`

You could refer the [nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) link to know more about the six states.